# Change of language on login page changes (again) after successful login

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Consider this scenario, which I also noticed at the demo site.

On the login page, https://spartacus-training.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/login , I tried changing the language to Japanese.. Looks good as the URL changes to https://spartacus-training.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/electronics-spa/ja/USD/login and the ja translations were applied. I also notice the change in language in the requests.

However, upon successful login, the language reverts back to `en` (as seen in the URL and the homepage) instead of `ja`

Is this a bug, or is there a proper way to handle the change in language during (and after) login?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, please open an issue on our [Github](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues).

This issue is happening because by default Spartacus will remember the last page the user was on and redirect him there. Since the last URL contains `en` the language is switched back to English.

This issue only happens when you change the language right before login.

Additionally, if you remove the `language` parameter from your `urlParameters` you will notice that the issue is gone.

If this issue is blocking, you could extend `AuthRedirectService` and modify the redirect method to take the language into account.